# Javascript: Trying to set function as a member of an object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function-pointers

I'm teachimg myself Javascript by porting a C# algebra expression compiler to Javascript.  I have an OpBank object that stores the attributes of each operator, e.g., it's symbol and a pointer to a function that implements the operator.  I know JS doesn't have function pointers but I don't know what else to call it.

When I try to load the page, I get the following error:

"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'Plus': object is null or undefined"

The error occurs when the browser tries to parse the Operators array at the bottom, it's complaining about the OpBank.Plus.  I tried OpBank.Plus, OpBank.Plus(), just plain old Plus, and this.Plus.  In any case I can't get it to recognize the Plus function when the Operators array gets loaded.

```
var OpBank = {
    Plus: function (left, right) {
        return (left + right);
    },

    Minus: function (left, right) {
        return (left - right);
    },

    Operators: [
      (new KeyValuePair("+", new ABinaryOperator("+", 1, OpType.Binary, "+", OpBank.Plus))),
      (new KeyValuePair("-", new ABinaryOperator("-", 1, OpType.Binary, "-", OpBank.Minus)))
      ]
}
```

Is what I'm attempting not possible?  Should I use the constructor syntax for OpBank instead, i.e., var ObBank = function(){} then use prototype to add the functions and array?  I didn't want to do that because I need only one OpBank for the life of the app and I don't want every method to have to instantiate a new OpBank because it's a pretty big object (only part of it is shown above).

Comment: Ugh, you are using IE/WSH to learn JavaScript? Better use a sane environment such as [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) for it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OpBank` does not exist yet while the object literal is evaluated.

You can simply split it into two steps though:

```
var OpBank = {
    Plus: function (left, right) {
        return (left + right);
    },

    Minus: function (left, right) {
        return (left - right);
    }
}

OpBank.Operators = [
    (new KeyValuePair("+", new ABinaryOperator("+", 1, OpType.Binary, "+", OpBank.Plus))),
    (new KeyValuePair("-", new ABinaryOperator("-", 1, OpType.Binary, "-", OpBank.Minus)))
];
```

Comment: Thank you ThiefMaster!  It's amazing how in software the solution to most insurmountable problems is most often very simple.

Comment: BTW, @ThiefMaster thanks for the fast replies too.  I'll have to look into node.js too - thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

this should work, at least on firebug console.

```
var testObj = {
    first: function(){
        console.log("first");
    },
    second: function(){
        console.log("second");
    },
    third: function(){
        return typeof this.first;
    }
};
testObj.third();
```